# Compare as ints in a gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to cast a string to an int and compare it to an int all in a gsp if statement.

Right now I have `${model > 0} ${model}`

Which outputs `true 0`

how do I cast model to an int in a gsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

```
${(model.toInteger()) > 0}
```

or

```
${(model as int) > 0}
```

If you want to avoid all of the above then populate the `model` as integer right from the controller before sent to view, so that you do not have to do the conversion every time you need.

On the other hand having an `int` converted to `String` is something you can do eyes closed.

Comment: what happens if model is empty or unable to be converted to an int?

Comment: Good Question. Have you tried that? If you are setting the model in controller with an int value then those checks should have been taken off as well, I would assume.

Comment: Are you sure? Try that again. If the model is populated with `int` then obviously you would not need any casting. But it should work well if you use the way it is mentioned in your question.

Comment: Actually many people convert to string very poorly; perhaps keeping one's eyes open is a good idea. You often see `"" + foo` as a to-string approach, but this creates a new StringBuilder/StringBuffer which appends both values and then its `toString()` is used as the new value. But `String.valueOf(foo)` is almost always going to be a lot more efficient. Of course in Groovy we can just use `foo as String`

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I have come across geniuses who use implementations like `new String("foo")` and `new Long(3)`. I can understand `"" + foo` being a common approach in JavaScript and would be one of the reason of pollution in Java/Groovy devs who work both on client and server side. :) +1 for usage of `*.valueOf()` [Effective Java]